# Inconvenientes actualizando registro mediante plano

Tags: php, sql

Estoy intentando cargar un plano para que actualice el grupo promoción. Tengo la siguiente opción de select, cuando se selecciona la opción 4 que es referencia proveedor,es necesario crear una tabla temporal para que desde está realice el  update a la tabla que se desea

```
//opcion select 
select id="subir_con" name="planoc1">
option value="1">Codigo de Barra</option>
option value="2">Codigo de Plu</option>
option value="3">Codigo de referencia</option>
option value="4">Codigo de referencia proveedor</option>
/select>
```

Y esta es la indicación que se le da al programa.

1. se crea la temporal
2. se insertan los datos del archivo
3. hago un select con un jion para traer los datos que se necesitan para poder hacer el update (esto se hace ya que en la tabla que se va hacer el update, no se tiene el campo d_referencia_proveedor) y se genera la temporal grupo_promocion_tmp2
4. con esta ultima tabla generada se realiza el update.

```
    if ($planoc1 == 4) {
      $sql = "create temp table grupo_promocion_tmp".

      "(d_referencia_prov char(40) not null,".
      "grupo_promocion char(5));";

      $vectorDeConsultas[$idxDeConsultas] = $sql;
      $idxDeConsultas = $idxDeConsultas + 1;

      $sql = " INSERT INTO grupo_promocion_tmp".
      " (d_referencia_prov,grupo_promocion)".
      " VALUES ('$campo1','$grupo_promocion');";

      $vectorDeConsultas[$idxDeConsultas] = $sql;
      $idxDeConsultas = $idxDeConsultas + 1;

      $sql = " SELECT b.c_producto,b.d_referencia_prov,a.grupo_promocion".
      " FROM  grupo_promocion_tmp a, m_productos b".
      " WHERE a.d_referencia_prov=b.d_referencia_prov ".
      " INTO TEMP grupo_promocion_tmp2 WITH NO LOG";

      $vectorDeConsultas[$idxDeConsultas] = $sql;
      $idxDeConsultas = $idxDeConsultas + 1;

      $sql = " DROP TABLE grupo_promocion_tmp";

      $vectorDeConsultas[$idxDeConsultas] = $sql;
      $idxDeConsultas = $idxDeConsultas + 1;

      $sql = "UPDATE dt_productos SET".
      "grupo_promocion =(select  grupo_promocion FROM grupo_promocion_tmp2
      WHERE dt_productos.c_producto = grupo_promocion_tmp2.c_producto)
      WHERE c_producto in (select c_producto from grupo_promocion_tmp2)
      "; 

    $vectorDeConsultas[$idxDeConsultas] = $sql;
    $idxDeConsultas = $idxDeConsultas + 1;

    }
```

al ejecutar la opción solo ejecuta la ultima sentencia y me genera error -206 indicando que no existe grupo_promocion_tmp2.

eh omitido algún paso?

Comment: Por favor incluye el código con el que ejecutas los comandos SQL. También indica que motor de base de datos utilizas (MySQL, PostgreSQL, etc.)

Comment: En al menos dos de tus cadenas `$sql` hay error cuando concatenas usando el `.`, ya que omites un espacio que separe la primera línea de la segunda: Por ejemplo: `$sql = "create temp table grupo_promocion_tmp"."(d_referencia_prov char(40) not null..."` y también: `$sql = "UPDATE dt_productos SET"."grupo_promocion =(select  grupo_promocion FROM grupo_promocion_tmp2...` por eso la tabla **`grupo_promocion_tmp2`** no se está creando.

Comment: @A.Cedano ya realice la corrección que me indicas, si realizo la prueba directamente en mi consola, ejecutando los Querys, no me genera nungun error. se realiza la actualización correctamente. crea la temporal, realiza el select y se crea la temporal grupo_promocion_tmp2 sin nungun incoveniente, cress que algo mas este afectando el proceso

Comment: En el código aparece en efecto una instrucción SQL para crear la tabla temporal, pero dicha tabla no se creará si no ejecutas la consulta, ahí sólo creas la instrucción, pero nunca la mandas a la conexión de la bd para que se cree la tabla. Por cierto, edita la pregunta y coloca que tipo de BD estás usando (MySQL, Oracle... u otra).